# The use of "tearing" in some programs comments

Tags: c

when I read some C programs, I find some comments, such as "tearing events" "structure which contains the tearing information data" "tearing analysis".It's confusing for me who don't have English as a first language to understand the meaning of word "tearing". So how to understand it?

```
`typedef struct tagRmsTearingServiceInfo
{
    UINT32  nvmLastPhysErrAddr;     ///< NVM physical address of last defective sector
    UINT8   nvmErrorCnt;            ///< NVM error counter for Map RAM-Init
    UINT8   nvmUnrecErrorCnt;       ///< NVM unrecoverable error counter
    UINT8   analysisData[10];       ///< 10 bytes for IFX internal use for tearing analysis
} RMS_TEARING_SERVICE_INFO;
/** Volatile FL Mailbox Area declarations */
typedef struct tagVolatileFlMailboxArea
{
    UINT16                      version;
    UINT16                      mailboxStatus;
    UINT16                      mailboxUpdateInfo;
    UINT8                       rfu_000[2];
    UINT32 volatile             interfaceActivationInfo;
    PIFX_MAILBOX_PAGE2          ifxMailboxPage2Addr;
    RMS_TEARING_SERVICE_INFO    rmsTearingServiceInfo;
    UINT8                       rfu_010[76];
    UINT32                      flStartMode;
    UINT8                       secFLTMDownloadKey[16];
} VOLATILE_FL_MAILBOX_AREA;`
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this word in computing, can you show examples?

Comment: Ask whoever wrote the code to explain the comments. I've never seen either of those terms.

Comment: It might be specific to the application of those programs, it's not a generic computer term.

Comment: What C programs are you reading? Can you give us some examples? I tried punching all three of the phrases you gave into my favorite search engine and no code showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tearing is a bit of a domain specific term. And nemequ has already mentioned the most common domain, related to GPU HW and programming.

In your case, based on the comment keywords NVM, IFX, etc. I suspect tearing refers to interrupted NVM operations. See e.g. [TLE987xQX BF BootROM User Manual](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE987xQX-BootROM-User-Manual-14-Infineon.pdf-UM-v01_04-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625d5945ed015d7f3eb4010080)

It's implicitly defined in the paragraph:

> reduce the risk of data loss in case of interrupted NVM operations
>   (tearing events)

And here:

> a NVM program or erase operation interrupted by any reset or power
>   loss (tearing events).

Also see [5.4.4.2 Tearing-safe Programming](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE987xQX-BootROM-User-Manual-14-Infineon.pdf-UM-v01_04-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625d5945ed015d7f3eb4010080) from that same manual.

> In TLE987xQX, the mapping mechanism of the non-linearly mapped sector
>   is used like a log-structured file system. When a page is programmed
>   in this sector, the old values are not physically overwritten, but a
>   different physical page (spare page) in the same sector is programmed.
>   If the programming fails, the old values are still present in the
>   sector and user can decide, by means of a specific input parameter of
>   the user programming routine (refer to Table 5-17), whether the old
>   values or the new failing values should be physically kept in the
>   sector. When an erase or write procedure is interrupted by a power
>   down, this is identified during the reconstruction of the MapRAM
>   content after the next reset. In this case, the service algorithm
>   routine is automatically started and repairs the NVM state exploiting
>   the fact that either the old or the new data (or both) are fully valid

Comment: Yes, the program is from infineon's chip(SLE97 serials).

Comment: Yes, well I think the definition above pretty much holds.  In graphics tearing is basically what happens when the buffer gets scanned out mid write.   In your case tearing events, seem to be any type of interruption during the NVM write.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this makes sense in the context you're seeing it, but the only use of "tearing" in computing I'm familiar with is when data from different frames is displayed on screen simultaneously.

Wikipedia has [an article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing) if you'd like more data.

If that's not the "tearing" you're encountering, perhaps you could provide a bit more context?  If the code is open source, linking to it would be great.